# Kак сделать, чтобы кнопка убирала все элементы?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно, чтобы кнопка (3 строка снизу) убирала все элементы. 40 минут сижу, не могу понять, что не так

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

a = Tk()
a.geometry('350x150')
a.resizable(False, False)
text = ttk.Label(a, text = 'хочешь, я сброшу а тебя 250000 тысяч тонн тротила?').place(x = 30, y = 30)

def da():
    for i in range(5):
        da = Tk()
        da.geometry('350x150')
        da.resizable(False, False)
        f = ttk.Label(da, text = '10000 тонн тротила').place(x = 120, y = 30)
        g = ttk.Button(da, text='нажми, чтобы убрать весь мусор', width=35, command = da.destroy).place(x=70, y=90)


knopkada = ttk.Button(a, text = 'да', width = 10, command = da).place(x=70, y=90)
knopkanet = ttk.Button(a, text = 'нет', width = 10).place(x = 200, y = 90)
a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Нужно уточнить, что вы хотите убирать. У вас главное окно, 2 кнопки и 1 текст (Label). Вы хотите убрать эти 3 элементы, чтобы главное окно осталось пустым?

Comment: необходимо убрать все созданные циклом for окна

Answer (score 1):

Создайте отдельный Frame (слой простыми словами) и помещайте туда элементы, которые планируете удалять. Если хотите удалить, то используйте `Frame.destroy()` и пересоздавайте Frame. Если же скрыть (данные введенные и свойства сохранятся) то в вашем случае `Frame.place_forget()`. Только не забудьте размещать Frame в окне!!!

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как я это сделал?

Я в вашем коде только добавил несколько строк и в одной вашей убрал `da.`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

a = Tk()
a.geometry('350x150')
a.resizable(False, False)
text = ttk.Label(a, text='хочешь, я сброшу а тебя 250000 тысяч тонн тротила?').place(x=30, y=30)

new_windows = []                      # здесь добавил

def da():                             
    def destroy():                    # здесь добавил
        for w in new_windows[:]:      # здесь добавил
            new_windows.remove(w)     # здесь добавил
            w.destroy()               # здесь добавил
            
    for i in range(5):
        da = Tk()
        new_windows.append(da)        # здесь добавил
        da.geometry('350x150')
        da.resizable(False, False)
        f = ttk.Label(da, text='10000 тонн тротила').place(x=120, y=30)
        g = ttk.Button(da, text='нажми, чтобы убрать весь мусор', width=35, command= destroy).place(x=70, y=90)
                                                                            # здесь ↑ убрал da.

knopkada = ttk.Button(a, text='да', width= 10, command=da).place(x=70, y=90)
knopkanet = ttk.Button(a, text='нет', width=10).place(x=200, y=90)
a.mainloop()
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Ссылки на (циклом `for`) созданные окна нужно где-то сохранить, чтобы мы в дальнейшем знали, чего нам нужно удалить. Для их хранения я создал пустой список:

   ```
   new_windows = []
   ```
2. Я добавил функцию, которая будет эти укна удалять (и тоже удалять ccылки на не их из списка `new_windows`):

   ```
   def destroy():               
       for w in new_windows[:]: 
           new_windows.remove(w)
           w.destroy()
   ```
3. Ссылку на каждое ново созданное окно я добавил в список `new_windows`:

   ```
   new_windows.append(da)
   ```
4. Имя функции из пункта 2, т.е. `destroy`, я применил к параметру `command=` вместо вашего `da.destroy`:

   ```
   g = ttk.Button(da, text='нажми, чтобы убрать весь мусор', width=35, command=destroy).place(x=70, y=90)
   ```
5. Но и еше во всем вашем коде я убрал проблы перед и за `=` во всех ключевых параметрах, чтобы он выл в соответствии с [PEP 8 - руководством по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-10):

   > Не используйте пробелы вокруг знака =, если он используется для обозначения именованного аргумента или значения параметров по умолчанию.

---